# What does | do in method parameters?

Tags: php, conventions

I have been reading PHP conventions in OOP and come across the `|` operator/symbol which I cannot find any information on. After trial and error testing in an enviroment, I found that if the parameter is not a data-type int then the variable to the right of the parameter is outputted.

For example, let's use a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    const FROM_DB = 1;
    const PUBLIC_ONLY = 0;

    public static function getSomething($input, $db = 0, $public = 1) {
        return $input;
    }
}
```

This use-case would return 1:

```
echo MyClass::getSomething( 'test' | MyClass::FROM_DB | MyClass::PUBLIC_ONLY );
```

This use-case would return 7:

```
echo MyClass::getSomething( 6 | MyClass::FROM_DB | MyClass::PUBLIC_ONLY );
```

Finally, this use-case would return 'test':

```
echo MyClass::getSomething( 'test' , MyClass::FROM_DB | MyClass::PUBLIC_ONLY );
```

I do not understand what the `|` is doing in this? [I found it here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Coding_conventions/PHP). Can anyone explain what this is called and how it is used correctly?

Thank's in advance, [see it working here](https://3v4l.org/iT7ZS).

Comment: It is a `bitwise` operator, search on that. `1, 2, 4, 8, 16` etc set a bit in binary to 1 that you can compare against. `1|2` dont match, but `1|3` do as `2+1` make 3, meaning the bit in integer 3 is set in 1 as well. Very useful for flags

Comment: Seem's confusing, I take it that it's used for mathematics? @Xorifelse

Comment: Not at all, simply put you can save up to 32 booleans in 1 32 bit integer. This method saves a lot of storage in a database and allows for awesome 1 liners instead of nested if elses and its extremely fast.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301

Answer (score 1):

It's a bitwise OR operator.

[bitwise operations wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)

Comment: Its discouraged to place a link only answer.